# What is correct Swift 3 data type for complex key pair values for JSONSerialized URLRequest

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I need to pass data like the following:

```
{
    "key":"355-3a34c",
    "status": [
        {
            "car info": [
                {
                    "body": "composite",
                    "doors": "standard",
                    "type": "sedan"
                }
            ],
            "trim": "luxury",
            "headlights": "led",
            "tires": 4,
            "step": "prepare for display",
            "soapType": "soft scrub",
            "attributes": []
        }, 
        {
            "step": "display",
            "days": 30,
            "location": "front"
        }
    ]
}
```

into a `URLRequest` after `JSONSerialization`:

```
let convertedString = String(data: myData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) // the data will be converted to the string
```

A few things to notice:

1. One of the keys is repeated (`"step"`)
2. There is a complex key: `{ "car info": [{ "body": "composite", "doors": "standard", "type": "sedan" }]`

I was able to load the data into an dictionary of dictionaries which enabled me to have duplicate keys.

However, I of course discovered that since data is not guaranteed to retain the order in which it was entered, the output was unusable since I need to retain the order of data to retain its meaningfulness.

I'm looking for a data type that can:

1. handle duplicate keys
2. handle complex data
3. be an acceptable data type for `JSONSerialization`
4. retains the order of data as was entered

I came across the dictionary literal data type and converted my data to it. It didn't seem to accept the complex data type of `{ "car info": [{ "body": "composite", "doors": "standard", "type": "sedan" }].`

Furthermore, when I omitted the complex data structure, just for testing, I got this error when it is being serialized as a dictionary literal:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'.
```

What data type or combination of data types can I use for Swift 3 that meets the criteria I need?

Big thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use a Swift data-type and `JSONSerialization` -- you can just construct the string yourself using string concatenation and formatting.

Comment: Don't I need JSON Serialization? I thought JSONSerialization produced output like this that I need to create: 3a7b2273 65232369 636e4994 ...

Comment: `{"car info":[{"body":composite,"doors":"standard","type":"sedan"}].` That's not complex, it's a Dictionary with one key ("car info") and the corresponding value is an array with only one object (a dictionary). "1) handle duplicate keys": No. You don't want that, you want a key, with an array (which have an order).

Comment: JSON is a standard. It accepts Dictionary, Array, String, Number (and null). That's all. If you try to have a dict with various same keys, you'll have an issue, you can try on https://jsonlint.com `{"h": "v","h": "v2"}` you'll get reject. You are in my opinion missing the fact that you can have Arrays.

Comment: I didn't think arrays will work because I have mixed data types, some string some integers. I think I have to define the data type when I create a string. Using Any as a type didn't seem to work. I will try a concatenated string, using single quotes to enclose double qouted text as I need to keep as quotes. Thanks

Comment: I think dictionary[String : AnyObject] in dictionary[String : AnyObject] will be solution.

Comment: "I didn't think arrays will work because I have mixed data types, some string some integers." And how is that incompatible with an Array? Clearly, if you give us the real structure (real sample), we can help you. But still, it depends on your backend (API). It shouldn't accept dictionary with multiples keys as same value. Either reject the JSON, or simply keep only the "first" value encountered. Why? As previously said, JSON is a standard. If you are violating the standard, that's up to you (not easy and not safe proof), but I think you are adding to much useless work there.

Comment: Here's how I resolved my problem: 1) used Lou Franco's suggestion to treat my content as a string (substituting " with \")  2), I converted the string to a data type with this:         let carData = carString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)  3) attached the carData data object to the request.httpBody and was then able to make a request and get a response back. Thanks Lou for the tip that I didn't have to use a JSON object to complete this process.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONSerialization` will not let you control the order of keys, but you don't need to use it to make JSON-like text.

You can just append a bunch of strings and then encode it to Data yourself.